# CasperJS scraping result from the terminal

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Let's say I've got one main url stored in a variable.

var google = 'http://www.google.com';

If I wanna search the word dog from the google var for example, from the terminal and scrape all the results how can I do this? For example:

casperjs test.js dog

Comment: With a paid web developer.

Comment: A quick play with google indicates that query strings look something like: `https://www.google.co.uk/#q=dog`. Therefore, your console application needs to get `dog` from the argument list, put it into a query string (as demonstrated) and then webcrawl the results. Look at nodejs documentation for command line argument guides and casperjs documentation for web crawling advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam!

Comment: Evolutionxbox I just asked for a direction, didn't want anyone to solve for me. Idk whats your problem. Thought this website is all about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a documentation regarding [App Arguments in NodeJS](https://code-maven.com/argv-raw-command-line-arguments-in-nodejs).

Read this and start writing your app. 
After that you might need regular expressions. Here is an example how to get all occurrences of a `dog` in a string

```
var str = 'red dog jumps over brown dog';
var regexp = /dog/gi;
var matches_array = str.match(regexp);

console.log(matches_array);
```

These are only hints on how to achieve this.

If you have any other question regarding this, create a new question with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a specific problem

Comment: Thanks a lot Kukic :)